# C# MongoDB Repository Architecture

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository-pattern

Our project recently migrated from SQL database to noSQL database (mogoDB) with using official 10gen driver. Project is based on MVVM using Prism framework.

We are using generic repositories - repository per collection.

Here comes few questions:

1. Should repistory contains only basic CRUD operations, or can
   there be more specific operations, for example to fetch user based
   on some specific values.
2. For binding purposes, we need some kind of automapping, the
   question is, in which layer should it be done? For example: 'Book'
   has 'AuthorId', but in View/ViewModel, we are binding to
   'Book.Author.name' ('Author' instead of 'AuthorId' would be unmapped
   property, of course).
3. Is it good practice to access some Repository from another generic
   Repository? Should they be visible to each other?

Comment: How did you answer these questions for your SQL-based implementation? It wouldn't necessarily need to be different. There are lots of ways to do this and the answers will vary a lot.

Comment: Also -- you may find that your data structures need to be rethought. `Book.Author.Name` for example would likely require an extra query. You'll need a more complex "auto mapper" to handle these types of requests.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - In SQL implementation, repositories contains 'Using pattern' (due to working with dbcontext) and 'higher level' data access operations (not only pure CRUD). Now there is no context. I'm not sure what is the best practice about repositories, whether to expose collection and provide only CRUD operations, OR keep collection private and provide more than CRUD operations (some querying methods).

Comment: I've personally found doing CRUD+operations to be a reasonable pattern, especially as MongoDB CRUD only operations aren't very useful generally speaking (too limited).

Comment: Voting to close. 3 questions and not one specific one as the FAQ states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally, we decided to use following approach:

1. Generic repositories (repository per collection) contains basic CRUD operations and simple methods for getting entities based on some specific values - strictly data access methods.
2. ViewModel layer does provide "completing" unmapped properties, instead of repository layer.
3. Therefore no cross refference between repositories is needed.